# Array values repeating multiple times in the console

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3

My problem probably is silly but I am unable to find the mistake I am making. I am checking the contents of the array in the browser and the contents are repeating multiple times. The values seem to be getting stored multiple times whereas they have to be stored only once. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

JS:

```
getCSVFile: function(bucketList){
    var counter, j = 0;
    var str = "aws-billing-csv";
    var csvBucketArr = [];
    bucketList.forEach(function(bucket, index) {
        (function(bucketId){        
            s3Client.listObjects(params = {Bucket: bucketId }, function(err, data) {
               if (err) {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Could not load objects from ' + bucketID;
                }
                else{
                  data.Contents.forEach(function(content,contentIndex){
                        var bucketObj = {};
                        var fileKey = content.Key;
                        if(fileKey.search(str) != -1) {
                           bucketObj[fileKey] = {
                                lastModified    : content.LastModified,
                                bucketName      : bucketId,
                                fileKey         : fileKey
                            }
                            if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(bucketObj)){
                                csvBucketArr.push(bucketObj);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    csv = csvBucketArr;
                }
                    // if(csvBucketArr.length!==0)
                    //     console.log("csvBucketArr :: ",csvBucketArr);   

                    app.storeInDB(csvBucketArr);  
            });
        }(bucket.bucketName));
    });
},

storeInDB : function(csvBucketArr){
    var file, fileDate, fileName;
    //extracting the date from the filename
    for(var i=0; i<csvBucketArr.length;i++){
        if(csvBucketArr.length!==0){
            console.log('in storeDB :: ', 'csvBucketArr :: ', csvBucketArr);
         }
    }
 }
```

**EDITED:**
The getCSVFile is invoked in the sortBucket function. The bucketList is the list of sorted buckets. I have included rest of the code below. The startApp function gets called in the onDeviceReady.

```
startApp: function() {
    accKey = $("#accessKey").val();
    secKey = $("#secretKey").val();
    if (empty(accKey)) {
        alert("AccessKey and SecretAccessKey fields are empty! Please enter values and Retry!");
        $("#accessKey").focus();
    } else {
        if (empty(secKey)) {
            alert("AccessKey and SecretAccessKey fields are empty! Please enter values and Retry!");
            $("#accessKey").focus();
        } else {
            var bucketListObj = {};
            AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId: accKey,
                secretAccessKey: secKey
            });

            s3Client = new AWS.S3();

            $("#page2").css("display: block; background: url(../img/BG.png);");
            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2");

            var bucketCount;
            s3Client.listBuckets(function(err, data) {
                if (err){ 
                    alert("Error :: ", err); 
                } 
                else {
                    $("#page2").css("display: block; background: url(../img/BG.png);");
                    $('#start').css('display: none;');

                    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change","#page2");
                    for (var index in data.Buckets) {
                        var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
                        var listContent = document.createElement("li");
                        listContent.innerHTML = "<p> Bucket Name: " + bucket.Name + "     Creation Date: " + bucket.CreationDate + "</p>";
             document.getElementById('resultList').appendChild(listContent);
                            bucketCount = index;
                        }
                    $('#start').replaceWith($('#page2').html());

                        var bucketListArr = [];
                        for (var index in data.Buckets) {
                            var bucket = data.Buckets[index];

                            //if(bucketList[index] == null) bucketList[index] = [];
                            bucketListArr.push({
                                "bucketName": bucket.Name,
                                "creationDate": bucket.CreationDate
                            });

                        }
                    }

                app.sortBucket(bucketListArr, "creationDate");
            });
        }
    }
},

sortBucket: function(bucketList, strParamToSortOn) {
    var sortedBucketList = [];

    bucketList.sort(function (a, b) {
        var dateA = a.creationDate, dateB = b.creationDate;
        return dateB - dateA;
    });

    sortedBucketList = bucketList;

    //console.log("Sorted List :: ", sortedBucketList);
    app.getCSVFile(sortedBucketList);
},
```

All help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the edit above

Comment: Just a quick guess: Shouldn't `app.storeInDB(csvBucketArr);` be outside of the `bucketList.forEach(...);`?

Comment: logically yes. but the csvBucketArr returns a zero length outside the bucketList.forEach().

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot that this is async. You can try to add the index to your IIFE and do something like `(function(bucketId, bucketIndex) { ... if (bucketIndex === bucketList.length - 1) {app.storeInDB(csvBucketArr); } ... }(bucket.bucketName, index)`. So you only store the array once when the last element is handled.